# How to start Blackberry Programming?

Tags: java, blackberry

for the past one month i am working on Android,and now i have to work on Blackberry with java.I don't know how to start it.so please guide me and provide some links to learn Blackberry.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.blackberryforums.com/

Comment: [Blackberry Developer Zone](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/)

Comment: [Useful links for novice and experienced programmers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=13264)

Comment: **[BlackBerry Development Guidelines](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Development%20Guidelines)**

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Contrasting-MIDlets-and-BlackBerry-Java-Applications/ta-p/446792 You can take help of this link and also refer Beginning blackberry development by Anthony Rizk.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this book "Beginning BlackBerry Development" Copyright © 2009 by Anthony Rizk. It has some great examples to set you on the right track starting from the first few pages all to the end.